# What's the time complexity of this and how to make it 0(n)?

Tags: javascript, performance, time-complexity

Leetcode problem [Third Maximum Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/third-maximum-number) is asking for an O(n) solution.

Here's my solution, what's the time complexity of this? and how to make it  0(n)? I thought `reduce` actually was 0(n), but maybe it's not? And what time complexity is `sort`?

```
var thirdMax = function(nums) {

    var arr = nums.reduce((unique, element) =>{
        return unique.includes(element) ? unique : [...unique, element]
    }, []);     
    arr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    console.log(arr);

    if(arr.length < 3){
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        return arr[2]
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reduce` iterates over the input array and checks whether any of the elements in another array match, which has complexity `O(N^2)` (worst-case, every item has to be checked against every other item).

Sorting an array has complexity `O(N log N)`.

So, overall, the worst-case complexity is `O(N^2)`.

I'd iterate while keeping track of 3 persistent variables - the highest number found so far, the 2nd highest, and the 3rd highest. Because it looks like they also want to prohibit duplicates from being counted, use a Set to keep track of the numbers which have been seen so far. `Set.has` is `O(1)`, so there's no additional complexity to worry about:

```js
var thirdMax = function(nums) {
  let highest = -Infinity;
  let secondHighest = -Infinity;
  let thirdHighest = -Infinity;
  const numsSeen = new Set();
  nums.forEach((num) => {
    if (numsSeen.has(num)) {
      return;
    }
    numsSeen.add(num);
    
    if (num > highest) {
      [highest, secondHighest, thirdHighest] = [num, highest, secondHighest];
    } else if (num > secondHighest) {
      [secondHighest, thirdHighest] = [num, secondHighest];
    } else if (num > thirdHighest) {
      thirdHighest = num;
    }
  });
  return thirdHighest === -Infinity
  ? highest
  : thirdHighest;
};

console.log(
  thirdMax([1, 2, 3]),
  thirdMax([1, 2, 3, 4]),
  thirdMax([2,2,3,1])
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is this 0(n)?

Comment: Yes, all the operations inside the `forEach` are `O(1)`, so the `forEach` itself is `O(N)`, worst-case.